# Value of null while making form validation with VueJS

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

I am trying to make some form validations, but keep getting the same error everytime.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

This is the html input

```
<label>Name of person</label>
<input v-model="model.cl_name" type="text" id="name"/>
```

And the simple JS code is:

```
data () {
    return {
        model.cl_name: ''  // should it be like that? 
    }                      // because it's not a legit syntax and gives 
                           // error
},
methods: {
    checkRequiredFields () {
        if(this.model.cl_name == '') {  //should it be like that?
            alert("No value");
        }
   }
}
```

However, I can't get it working...

Updated comment.

Comment: If your input element is mounted by a VueJS component or the app, it might not be present at runtime so that `name` will return `undefined`. Instead, define `name` inside the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have completely changed your question now.

Here is the answer to your updated question:

You will need to setup your data attribute like this:

```
data () {
    return {
        model: {
            cl_name: ''
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I am sorry for the incorrect information I gave at first. This worked like a charm :) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scoping error. Try putting your name var inside your method.

```
methods: {
    checkRequiredFields () {
        var name = document.getElementById("name");

        if (name.value == "") {
            alert("No value");
        }
   }
}
```

On a side note, seeing you have the data attribute name as the v-model, why not check the data attribute directly?

Since you have an input binding with v-model, I would use that.

eg:

Template:

```
<label>Name of person</label>
<input v-model="name" type="text" id="name"/>
```

Javascript:

```
data () {
    return {
        name: ''
    }
},
methods: {
    checkRequiredFields () {
        if(this.name == '') {
            alert("No value");
        }
   }
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Should I use the v-model name or the ids' name?

Comment: I would suggest using the v-model binding you have already setup. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. However I have one more dumb question.Since I changed the v-model name to "name" only to be more readable. My real v-model is v-model="model.cl_name" how should I do it? I mean the syntax.

Comment: <label>Name of person</label>
 <input v-model="Model.cl_name" type="text" id="name"/>

Comment: it would be ```this.model.cl_name```, assuming that ```model``` is an object in your data attributes.

Comment: No, the project has back-end and front-end parts. The property cl_name is in the back-end part in a .java file which I do not write nor I have access.

Comment: Sorry, I guess if you don't have access then you can't use it. Hopefully you find my answer correct as it directly answers your initial question.

Comment: I updated my first post, can you look it up? I mean can't change the name of v-model. Because it gets it from the back-end part. Not that i can't use it.